# Getting error while inserting Options via Js

Tags: javascript, dom

I've just wrote this Js function and, although this works, I keep getting this error message on console:

```
Erro ao inserir options no seletor ... do tipo ... : ReferenceError: seletor is not defined
```

Call for the inserirOptions function:

```
for(var i in this.JsonTipoPgto) {
  this.inserirOptions(this.JsonTipoPgto[i].id, this.JsonTipoPgto[i].tipo_pagamento, this.almsSeletor, this.almsTipoSeletor);
}
```

My Js functions is like follows:

```
compSimplf.prototype.inserirOptions = function(id, valor, seletor, tipoSeletor) {
  try {
    if(tipoSeletor == 'id') {
      this.almsSelect = document.getElementById(seletor);
      this.gerarOptions(id, valor);
    } else if(tipoSeletor == 'classe') {
      var aClasse = document.getElementsByClassName(seletor);
      for(var i in aClasse) {
        this.almsSelect = aClasse[i];
        this.gerarOptions(id, valor);
      }
    }

  } catch(err) {
    console.log('%c Erro ao inserir options no seletor '+seletor+' do tipo '+tipoSeletor+': '+err, 'background: #A52A2A; color: #FFFFE0');
  }
};
```

The function that's generating the options:

```
compSimplf.prototype.gerarOptions = function(id, valor) {
  try {
    this.almsOption = document.createElement("option");
    this.almsOption.value = id;
    this.almsOption.text = valor;
    this.almsSelect.add(this.almsOption); //The error shows while running this line
  } catch(err) {
    console.log('%c Erro ao gerar options no seletor '+seletor+' do tipo '+tipoSeletor+': '+err, 'background: #A52A2A; color: #FFFFE0');
  }
};
```

Comment: Can you please show your code that calls it?

Comment: I've just added the call of the function.

Comment: `this.almsSeletor` must be undefined

Comment: Yep, what he said. Set a breakpoint in your console.

Comment: How can I do that Jim Speaker !?

Comment: Press F12 to bring up developer tools in Chrome, IE or Firefox. Dev tools will be your new best friend after you poke around a bit, experiment, and or read about their use.

Comment: Ok, added the breakpoint and the error appears exactly after execute that function

Comment: Set a breakpoint where the function is being called, then you can look at the values of the parameters being passed in. You should find that it's passing undefined to seletor. Then you can work backward from there to determine why it's undefined.